# How to stop multiple AVAudioPlayers from playing in swift?

Tags: ios, audio, swift, viewcontroller

I am very new to swift and I was a novice with Objective-C. Recently I started a soundboard app that plays many sounds on 3 different view controllers. For the apps next update I wanted to make it so it could play multiple sounds simultaneously and I did this by creating an individual audioPlayer for each button. So for each view controllers I would have 9 instances of AVAudioPlayers (One for each button) and when each button was pressed it would play one of them EX: audioPlayer8 would belong to the hitmarkerButton. I succesfully did this but now I want a way for the users to press a button to "reset" the sounds in the app. So for each view controller I already created an IBAction called stopPlayingSounds that should "reset" or stop playing all sounds from all view controllers. This is my first time asking a question here so please tell me if there is anything else I should include. Thank you.

Also each of the examples included below are just one of up to 9 examples for each view controller. PS - Each view controller is a page.

The "Sound Stopper" Button:

```
    @IBAction func stopPlayingSounds(sender: AnyObject) {

    }
```

An example of one of the buttons:

```
    @IBAction func hitmarkerButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    audioPlayer8 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: hitmarkerSound, error: nil)
    audioPlayer8.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer8.play()
}
```

Example of one of the declarations of the AVAudioPlayers:

```
var audioPlayer8 = AVAudioPlayer()
```

And lastly, an example of the creation of the actual sound:

```
    var hitmarkerSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hitmarker", ofType: "mp3")!)
```

Comment: audioPlayer8.stop() use this

Comment: @Sport That only stops it for that Audio PLayer. I need it to stop it for all instances of audio players which is audioPlayer1, audioPlayer2, audioPlayer3.... audioPlayer9. And there are up to 9 per view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to initialize your variables somewhere other than inside the button press methods, so you can see those variables after the method is over. I always heard it "what happens in a method stays in a method..."

So for example I'd put the declarations at the top of your view controller, and stuff them in an array:

```
var myAudioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer] //remember arrays start at 0 and go up to n-1
myAudioPlayers[0] = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound1, error: nil)
...
myAudioPlayers[8] = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound8, error: nil)
```

Then you'd have

```
@IBAction func hitmarkerButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    audioPlayer[7].prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer[7].play()
}
```

And you can use the array to quickly do:

```
@IBAction func stopPlayingSounds(sender: AnyObject) {
    foreach (ap in myAudioPlayers)
    ap.stop()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue for weeks (overlaid audio from every stream that has been loaded).  I eventually discovered that every `let` statement creates a new instance of `AVPlayer`, so the multi-threaded OS plays them all simultaneously. I solved my problem by creating a single `AVPlayer` at the class level with:

```
var vidPlayer:AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
```

and then just reassigned `vidPlayer` to new content each time with:

```
vidPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url) //where url was defined previously
```

The player restarts with the new content and only the most current audio stream.